# read a raw file and convert it to 8 bit

Tags: c++, matlab, visual-c++

I am trying to rewrite a matlab code into c++. 
It reads a file and do the deresolution on it and convert it to `8 bit`.

but the VC++ code does not work for all ranges of `max_den` and `min_den`. Specially when the there is a small difference between them. (I tried that range on Matlab, it works)

**MATLAB Code:**

```
fid = fopen(ORIGINAL_FILENAME,'r');
A = fread(fid,X*Y*Z,'int32=>int32')
D = uint8(255/double(Maximum_Density-Minimum_Density)*(A-Minimum_Density));
A = reshape(D,X,Y,Z);
fid=fopen(OUTPUT_FILENAME,'w');
fwrite(fid,A,'uint8');
fclose(fid);
```

**VC++ 2008 Code:**

```
int *input_buffer;
FILE *fp = fopen("file.raw","r");
FILE *new_fp = fopen("new_file.raw","w");
unsigned char *output_buffer;
output_buffer=new unsigned char[x*y*z];
input_buffer=new int[x*y*z];
fread(input_buffer,sizeof(int),x*y*z,fp);
for(int i=0;i<x*y*z;i++)
output_buffer[i]=255/(double::Parse(max_den)-double::Parse(min_den))*(input_buffer[i]-double::Parse(min_den));
fwrite(output_buffer,sizeof(unsigned char),x*y*z,new_fp);
fclose(new_fp);
fclose(fp);
```

For example when actual range of data is [-3023,3072] and the max_den=-3000, min_den=1000, it works well. but when you choose max_den=-1000, min den=1000, it doesn't work properly.
The raw file includes 3D data associated with a mhd file. When the range is not wide enough, the converted file becomes messy.

Comment: Your second code is `c`, you're sure you want it written in `C++`, not `C`?

Comment: In what way does it not work? What is the input value, max and min_den and the expected and actual output?

Comment: Oh and BTW your loop will run very much faster if you move the Parse(max_den) and Parse(min_den) outside the loop to create a couple of double variables that you then use inside the loop.

Comment: @Tim Bergel, or even 255/(double::Parse(max_den)-double::Parse(min_den)). You should also round the double result with double round(double number)
{
    return number < 0.0 ? ceil(number - 0.5) : floor(number + 0.5);
}

Comment: Also use a cast (unsigned char)floor(number + 0.5)

Comment: the second code is in visual C++ 2008

Comment: For example when actual range of data is [-3023,3072] and the max_den=-3000, min_den=1000, it works well. but when you choose max_den=-1000, min den=1000, it doesn't work properly.

Comment: The raw file includes 3D data associated with a mhd file. When the range is not wide enough, the converted file becomes messy.

Comment: I move the Parse(max_den) and Parse(min_den) outside the loop, and it makes it work faster. Also, I add casting and round function, but still doesn't work.